How to get the content of a notification in XCUITest?
How to get the content of a notification in XCUITest, specifically the notification's identifier
I have a piece of code in my app to show a notification as follows:
- (NSString *)showNotificationWithIdentifier:(NSString * _Nullable)identifier
                                        title:(NSString *)title
                                 description:(NSString *)description {
    NSString *_id;
    // No ID specified (automatic increment)
    if (identifier == nil) {
        NSUserDefaults *prefer = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:AfibNotificationManager.TAG];
        NSString *latestIdStr = [prefer stringForKey:AfibNotificationManager.LATEST_ID_KEY];
        int tmpId;
        if (latestIdStr == nil) {
            tmpId = INT_MIN;
        } else {
            tmpId = [latestIdStr intValue];
            tmpId += 1;
        }
        _id = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", tmpId];
        [prefer setValue:_id forKey:AfibNotificationManager.LATEST_ID_KEY];
    }
    // ID specified
    else {
        _id = identifier;
    }
    
    UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
    content.title = title;
    content.body = description;
    content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
    UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:_id content:content trigger:nil];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:nil];
    });
    
    return _id;
}

This is my UITest code:
- (void)checkNotification {
    
    XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
    [app launch];
    [app.buttons[@"btn"] tap]; //click button will call method showNotificationWithIdentifier to show notification
    
    XCUIApplication *springboard = [[XCUIApplication alloc];
    initWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.springboard"];
    XCUICoordinate *start = [app coordinateWithNormalizedOffset:CGVectorMake(0.5, 0.0)];
    XCUICoordinate *finish = [app coordinateWithNormalizedOffset:CGVectorMake(0.5, 1.5)];
    [start pressForDuration:0.1 thenDragToCoordinate:finish];
    XCUIElement *notification = springboard.buttons[@"NotificationCell"];
    XCTAssertTrue([notification waitForExistenceWithTimeout:5]);
    NSString *identifier = notification.identifier;
}

When I perform XCUITest to get notification information such as notification identifier, I encounter difficulties and it seems incorrect. Could you help me with a way to retrieve the notification identifier, label, and check if the notification has been displayed or not? Thank you.

Notification presentation is not something your app does, so it is not part of the system under test and you should not make any attempt to test it. You can mock the notification center to see whether your app configures and adds the notification as expected, but that would be a unit test, not a UI test.

Hi @matt , could you please give me an example about mocking the notification center by object-c(unit test)? Thank you very much.

That would be a different question. I'm responding to what you asked. I'm suggesting that you should complete revise your desires.
